# How to make the children of a flex item fill 100% of their parents height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple page with a header (which needs to take up 20% of the total page height) and container which I want to fill the remaining page height (80%).

The catch is that I want each child of the container to be 100% of the container height (so the container would need to expand to actually be 80% of the total page height * how ever many children there are.

Is it possible using Flexbox to make the container hold several elements each of which are the total height of the container?

I do not know how make an element both fill remaining space, and then use that as an indicator of total height.

Anyway, here is a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpweVj) - the simple html and css follows: My ideal result would be that each of the colored `divs` would be the full height of the `body` minus the `header` height and the container would expand to hold the items.

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
div.holder {
  flex: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.one {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

div.two {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

div.three {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

div.four {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>  
  </header>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="one">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      two
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      three
    </div>
     <div class="four">
      four
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7ndepwhz/)

css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: blue;
  height:20%
}

div.holder {
  height:80%; /* <------ make it of desired height */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

div.holder > div {
  min-height: 100%; /* <------ better to provide min-height */
}

div.one {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

div.two {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

div.three {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

div.four {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

html

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="four">four</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need flexbox?
Why not simply use viewport values (vw,vh)?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background: blue;
  height: 20vh;
}
div.holder {
  height: 80vh;
}

div.one {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

div.two {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

div.three {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

div.four {
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>  
  </header>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="one">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      two
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      three
    </div>
     <div class="four">
      four
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Or you can go with percentage values, it's pretty much the same. (but body and html need to have 100% height)

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
header { height: 20%; }
.holder { height: 80%; }
.holder > div { height: 100%; }
```